# Firebase CLI authentication problem in cloud shell

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to deploy a test web application using Firebase. I found this Google documentation to deploy a test application [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ivzz.png). I am able to clone a Github repository and enable Firebase on the project. The Firebase web app was created, and I used my Google account as an authentication method. I enabled the web app in Cloud Firestore, and everything seems to be working fine on the Firebase side.

[image: I used google as the sign in method]

[image: Google sign in was enabled]

[image: Test mode was used for the test]

My project is being deployed using GCP and running the application using Cloud Shell. The Firebase version installed is 9.22.0. I got to the point where I need to authorize the Firebase CLI with the following command:

```
firebase login
```

[image: documentation says to use this command to authorize the Firebase CLI in cloud shell]

According to the instructions, I'm supposed to get the following message: “Allow Firebase to collect CLI usage and error reporting information?” and authorize by pressing Y, and enter to generate an URL. I need to paste the URL in the browser to authenticate with the account being used to generate a verification code and then use it in the Cloud Shell prompt.

Once I run the firebase login command, it never prompts me with “Allow Firebase to collect CLI usage and error reporting information?” It generates the link, and I paste it in the browser and I get the following screen:

[image: Error I get when I try to authenticate]

I have tried cleaning the browser cookies thinking it was a browser issue, but I kept getting the same error. I have tried different browsers, but keep getting the same error. I recreated the project several times, but Cloud Shell never prompts me to allow Firebase. I have created the project in another GCP account, and we have the same problem. The instructions were followed according to the documentation, but I cannot move forward because it is not allowing me to authorize the Firebase CLI.  Does anyone have any insight on the issue? Any help would be very welcome.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ivzz.png) https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#3

Comment: Welcome, please post any code in the screenshots as text.

Comment: Thank you @Phix, the problem doesn't seem to be with the code.  I just want Firebase to establish connection with Cloud Shell.  The step where I get the error is exactly when I authenticate to log into Firebase

Comment: The OAuth redirect URL "sadsafdsdda.com" is definitely wrong. It doesn't exist and Google's auth service is trying to return you to your app. Wherever you set that, you need to correct it. It likely should have been `localhost` for testing or the URL to the deployed Firebase app (`https://YOUR-PROJECT.firebaseapp.com`).

Comment: Thank you DazWilkin, I tried using `localhost` and still unable to authorize Firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#sign-in-test-cli):

> The firebase login command opens a web page that connects to localhost on your machine. If you're using a remote machine and don't have access to localhost, run the command with the flag --no-localhost.

Run the following command in your terminal:

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

Tried the steps in the documentation you provided and I was able to launch the app successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Mabel A., I recreated the project and used `Firebase login --no-localhost` and I confirm that is generating the validation code.  I was able to to log into Firebase and was able to deploy the Web App.

Comment: Hi @AndresFiescoCasasola I'm glad it answered your question. Please accept the answer, that way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?